# Difficulty with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I'm having difficulty with IEnumerable and LINQ. Perhaps I don't understand it fully.

I have a data source of fake files ("PlumFile"), and some filters. Each filter has a `Fits(PlumFile)` that determines if the argument fits that filter. Each filter also has an enum indicating if it's "and", "or", or "not".

Here is how I'm trying to combine all those filters into a query:

```
    public ObservableCollection<PlumFile> FoundFiles
    {
        get
        {
            ObservableCollection<PlumFile> searchResults = new ObservableCollection<PlumFile>();

            // get the data source
            IEnumerable<PlumFile> query = PlumData.GetFiles();

            foreach (FilterConstraint filter in filters)
            {
                // debugging
                IList<PlumFile> oldQuery = query.ToList();

                switch (filter.QueryCombiningRule)
                {
                    case FilterConstraint.QueryRule.And:
                        query = query.Where(file => filter.Fits(file));
                        break;
                    case FilterConstraint.QueryRule.Or:
                        query = query.Concat(PlumData.GetFiles().Where(file => filter.Fits(file)));
                        break;

                    // is this really how I want to do 'not'?
                    case FilterConstraint.QueryRule.Not:
                        query = query.Where(file => !filter.Fits(file));
                        break;
                }

                // debugging
                IList<PlumFile> currQuery = query.ToList();

            }

            query = query.Distinct();

            foreach (PlumFile file in query)
            {
                searchResults.Add(file);
            }

            return searchResults;
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. For some queries, it works fine. For others, it fails.

If I have a single "and" filter, it works fine. Then I add a "not" filter that shouldn't filter out anything already selected, but everything is removed. Why is this?

(I'm doing this for a Silverlight 4 app, but I don't think it matters.)

**Update**:
One example of a filter constraint:

```
public class NameFilterConstraint : FilterConstraint
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override bool Fits(PlumFile plumFile)
    {
        return plumFile.Name.Contains(Name);
    }

    public override string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return ToString();
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("Name contains '{0}'", Name);
    }
}
```

**Update 2**: Here is a non-LINQ version that doesn't have the bugs I mentioned earlier:

```
public ObservableCollection<PlumFile> FoundFiles
        {
            get
            {
                ObservableCollection<PlumFile> searchResults = new ObservableCollection<PlumFile>(PlumData.GetFiles().ToList());

                foreach (FilterConstraint filter in filters)
                {
                    switch (filter.QueryCombiningRule)
                    {
                        case FilterConstraint.QueryRule.And:
                            foreach (PlumFile file in searchResults.ToList())
                            {
                                if (! filter.Fits(file))
                                {
                                    searchResults.Remove(file);
                                }
                            }
                            break;

                        case FilterConstraint.QueryRule.Or:
                            foreach (PlumFile file in PlumData.GetFiles())
                            {
                                if (filter.Fits(file))
                                {
                                    searchResults.Add(file);
                                }
                            }
                            break;

                        case FilterConstraint.QueryRule.Not:
                            foreach (PlumFile file in searchResults.ToList())
                            {
                                if (filter.Fits(file))
                                {
                                    searchResults.Remove(file);
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }

                return new ObservableCollection<PlumFile>(searchResults.Distinct());
            }
        }
```

So, I guess my problem is solved, although I'm still curious as to what I was doing wrong with the LINQ. Perhaps my intentions (made clear in the last example) were not translated into LINQ properly?

Comment: Can you include your code for the Fits method?

Comment: I spent 5 minutes staring at this, but my brain hurts just looking at the question as it stands :)

Comment: @Gravitas: Is that because I'm abusing LINQ? How can I do this in a less convoluted way?

Comment: Can not say about abusing LINQ, but you are exploiting a property for sure. A property is supposed to be light-weight and not involve much operations. This operation MUST be moved to a method.

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess here, but I wonder if this is a capture/closure issue. Try this:

```
    public ObservableCollection<PlumFile> FoundFiles
    {
        get
        {
            ObservableCollection<PlumFile> searchResults = new ObservableCollection<PlumFile>();

            // get the data source
            IEnumerable<PlumFile> query = PlumData.GetFiles();

            foreach (FilterConstraint filter in filters)
            {
                var localFilter = filter;
                // debugging
                IList<PlumFile> oldQuery = query.ToList();

                switch (filter.QueryCombiningRule)
                {
                    case FilterConstraint.QueryRule.And:
                        query = query.Where(file => filter.Fits(file));
                        break;
                    case FilterConstraint.QueryRule.Or:
                        query = query.Concat(PlumData.GetFiles().Where(file => localFilter.Fits(file)));
                        break;

                    // is this really how I want to do 'not'?
                    case FilterConstraint.QueryRule.Not:
                        query = query.Where(file => !localFilter.Fits(file));
                        break;
                }

                // debugging
                IList<PlumFile> currQuery = query.ToList();

            }

            query = query.Distinct();

            foreach (PlumFile file in query)
            {
                searchResults.Add(file);
            }

            return searchResults;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How would this make a difference?

Comment: Try it first and if it does, I'll explain why.

Comment: @Rosarch:  The lambda expressions in the Where clauses reference the filter loop variable.  The compiler will capture a reference to the filter loop variable, but not its value at the moment of reference.  When those lambdas are evaluated later (LINQ lazy eval, typically at the next conversion ToList()) the filter loop variable will probably be different from when the reference was made - the loop has moved on.  Assigning the loop variable to a local var and using the local var in the lambdas forces the compiler to capture the current value, not just a reference to the loop variable.

Answer (score 1):

On the face of it, I would suggest applying the filters as eager evaluation (not lazy).

Use .ToList() after applying all the filters inside loop + make "query" List. 
If that does not work, then you need to post "Fits" method also.